# Disable personal certificate from the command line on Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, certificate

In Windows XP I can do the following actions via the UI:

Launch certmgr.msc. From then, select a certificate under Personal -> Certificates, click on properties and select "Disable (or enable) for all purposes."

How do I do the same from the command line? Probably via the registry, but without having to click through those interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

One can use the [Certificate Manager Tool (Certmgr.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78byta0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) with the `/delete` parameter.

CertMgr is available as part of the Windows SDK, which you can download from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=84091.
Must be run as administrator.

An example of use :

```
certmgr -del -c -n "My Certificate Name" -s -r localMachine TrustedPublisher
```